# Unigram tagging in NLTK

Tags: nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, allennlp

Using `NLTK` Unigram Tagger, I am training sentences in `Brown Corpus`

I try different `categories` and I get about the same value. The value is around `0.9328`... for each `categories` such as `fiction`, `romance` or `humor`

```
from nltk.corpus import brown


# Fiction    
brown_tagged_sents = brown.tagged_sents(categories='fiction')
brown_sents = brown.sents(categories='fiction')
unigram_tagger = nltk.UnigramTagger(brown_tagged_sents)
unigram_tagger.evaluate(brown_tagged_sents)
>>> 0.9415956079897209

# Romance
brown_tagged_sents = brown.tagged_sents(categories='romance')
brown_sents = brown.sents(categories='romance')
unigram_tagger = nltk.UnigramTagger(brown_tagged_sents)
unigram_tagger.evaluate(brown_tagged_sents)
>>> 0.9348490474422324
```

Why is it that the case? is it because they are from the same `corpus`? or are their `part-of-speech` tagging is the same?

Comment: Could you please post your code so that we can try to reproduce this?

Comment: @RahulP I update the question with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are training and then evaluating the trained `UnigramTagger` on the same training data.  Take a look at the documentation of [nltk.tag](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html) and specifically the [part](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html#nltk.tag.sequential.NgramTagger) about evaluation.

With your code, you will get a high score which is quite obvious because your training data and evaluation/testing data is the same. If you were to change that where the testing data is different from the training data, you will get different results. My examples are below:

**Category: Fiction**

Here I have used the training set as `brown.tagged_sents(categories='fiction')[:500]` and the test/evaluation set as `brown.tagged_sents(categories='fiction')[501:600]`

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
import nltk

# Fiction    
brown_tagged_sents = brown.tagged_sents(categories='fiction')[:500]
brown_sents = brown.sents(categories='fiction') # not sure what this line is doing here
unigram_tagger = nltk.UnigramTagger(brown_tagged_sents)
unigram_tagger.evaluate(brown.tagged_sents(categories='fiction')[501:600])
```

This gives you a score of ~ 0.7474610697359513

**Category: Romance**

Here I have used the training set as `brown.tagged_sents(categories='romance')[:500]` and the test/evaluation set as `brown.tagged_sents(categories='romance')[501:600]`

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
import nltk

# Romance
brown_tagged_sents = brown.tagged_sents(categories='romance')[:500]
brown_sents = brown.sents(categories='romance') # not sure what this line is doing here
unigram_tagger = nltk.UnigramTagger(brown_tagged_sents)
unigram_tagger.evaluate(brown.tagged_sents(categories='romance')[501:600])
```

This gives you a score of ~ 0.7046799354491662

I hope this helps and answers your question.